# Simple modern cross-platform dlopen/loadLibrary wrapper in C++

Tags: c++, cross-platform, dynamic-library

I'm working on a cross platform project where I have to load dynamic libraries. I therefore created a very basic platform independent templated wrapper class around dlopen/loadLibrary that act like a factory class and return `unique_ptr<T>`s of the lib object.

But this is very unpractical in most of the cases, I therefore wondered, how can I design a simple wrapper that can do the following:

- Load a lib and become a factory on instances of that lib objects for when we have to use multiple instances of the lib object
- Create a self managed entity (a struct containing a unique ptr on the object and the handle on the lib maybe ?) for when we want to use only one instance of a lib object and not bother with a factory
- Use the library provided deleter (symbol "destroy") instead of the default one

Does this exist ? If not, what would be the best way to do this ?

My implementation so far:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#if _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <dlfcn.h> //dlopen
#endif

namespace utils
{

template <class T>
class DynLib
{
  public:
    DynLib() = default;
    ~DynLib()
    {
        if (handle_)
            closeLib(handle_);
    };

  private:
    bool printLibError()
    {
#if _WIN32
        std::cerr << GetLastError() << std::endl;
#else
        std::cerr << dlerror() << std::endl;
#endif
        return false;
    }

    void *openLib(const std::string &libName)
    {
#if _WIN32
        return LoadLibrary((libName + ".dll").c_str());
#else
        return dlopen((libName + ".so").c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
#endif
    }

    int closeLib(void *libHandle)
    {
#if _WIN32
        return FreeLibrary((HMODULE)libHandle);
#else
        return dlclose(libHandle);
#endif
    }

    void *loadSymbol(void *libHandle, const char *sym)
    {
#if _WIN32
        return (void *)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)libHandle, sym);
#else
        return dlsym(libHandle, sym);
#endif
    }

  public:
    bool open(const std::string &filename, const char *csym = "create", const char *dsym = "destroy")
    {

        if (!(handle_ = openLib(filename)))
            return printLibError();
        if (!(create = (T * (*)()) loadSymbol(handle_, csym)))
            return printLibError();
        if (!(destroy_ = (void (*)(T *))loadSymbol(handle_, dsym)))
            return printLibError();
        return true;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<T> createUnique()
    {
        return (std::unique_ptr<T>(create()));
    }

  private:
    void *handle_{nullptr};
    T *(*create)();
    void (*destroy_)(T *);
};
}
```

Comment: I believe that you've just described the [GNU libtool](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/) library.

Comment: libltdl to be precise: https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Using-libltdl.html

Comment: Have a look at the OpenGL loader libraries they are cross platform and must manage shared libs and locating entry points.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [Boost.DLL library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_dll.html)?
It provides examples on how implement plugins/factory methods.